# Resolution Limited to 1152x864 instead of 1680x1050 - Ubuntu 14.04.3, Nvidia 8800GTS

Tags: display-resolution

- GPU: Nvidia (BFG) 8800 GTS 320Mb
- Monitor: Acer 22"
- Max resolution supported by the GPU: 2560x1600
- Max resolution supported by the monitor: 1680x1050
- Resolution stuck at: 1152x864

I have spent almost two weeks so far trying to fix this resolution limit issue on Ubuntu 14.04:

1. I have gone through any result that comes up in Google in the first five pages
2. I have read at least 10-15 topics on this forum alone, and many more on other websites
3. I have tried the xrandr trick
4. I have tried the xconfig file trick
5. I have tried updating/reinstalling/uninstalling Nvidia drivers
6. Tried different versions of the Nvidia driver (official/unofficial/open-source/latest version/older versions)
7. checking the monitor plug, etc

NONE of these have worked at all. I have reinstalled my Ubuntu 14.04 three times (every time a completely clean install, formatting the "entire" hard disk), I even tried 15.10, Linux Mint, elemntaryOS, Korora, etc - since I thought the problem is only with Ubuntu, but I have the same problem on all these distributions.

I do not have this resolution limit problem on Windows at all, it is only on Ubuntu. I can go up to 1680x1050 on Windows.

It is so mental, and I have spent hours and hours trying any possible fix that I have found online, and absolutely nothing has worked.. Does anybody know any fixes for the issue?

[Nvidia X Server shows this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnF5Q.png)

Comment: The screenshot says, "CRT-0" which implies that the monitor is connected through a VGA cable, I would recommend any digital cable (DVI, HDMI, DP) over VGA. If that is not available try a *new* VGA cable that has not been bent much or is very flimsy. Through recent experience I know that VGA can support up to 1920x1200 but not all cables at all time in their lifecycle.

Comment: Yes, it is true that I am using a VGA cable to connect the monitor to my GPU. However, since my GPU does not support VGA cables, I am using a VGA-DVI adapter. But one thing to note is that, using the same adapter and configuration I was able to get the desired resolution in Ubuntu 11.10 back in the day..